# insert image to BLOB column in oracle

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, file-upload

i want to upload image and insert it to (BLOB)column in oracle , when i run it , no problem it give me "Done " but when i check DB the column for Photo is empty , what is the problem ? or  can insert to varchar?

```
public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);
    imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.ContentLength);
    return imageBytes;
}
```

this is the code to convert image from HttpPostedFileBase to byte[]
then i insert it inside column with name Photo
public string Createcontant(string articalname, string KEYWORD_NAME, string articalbody , HttpPostedFileBase file)

```
{

    Contant c1 = new Contant() ;
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
   if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
     c1.photo = ConvertToBytes(file);


            }
    try
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("photo", ConvertToBytes(file));

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("articalname", articalname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KEYWORD_NAME", KEYWORD_NAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("articalbody", articalbody);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parAddedUser", HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("articalbody", articalbody);

        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parUserAccount", userAccount);

        /***************************************************************************************/
        string sql = "insert into contact" +
                     "( ARTICL_ID, ARTICAL_NAME, IDATE, IUSER," +
                     "   KEYWORD_NAME, ARTICALBODY ,photo )" +
                     " Values " +
                     "(  CONTANT_SEQ.nextval, :articalname,sysdate,:parAddedUser," +
                     " :KEYWORD_NAME,:articalbody , :photo)";




        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();


        //Response.Redirect("~/Admin/UsersManagment.aspx", false);
        return "done";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

      
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert directly the BLOB with an INSERT statement, you have to insert first an empty_blob, then populate it.

See her for examples: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/oralob2.htm